# Check every URL in string to remove links of certain sites

Tags: php

I want to remove URLs of certain sites within a string

I used this:

```
<?php

$URLContent = '<p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></p><p><a href="https://www.anothersite.com/">AnotherSite</a></p>';

$LinksToRemove = array('google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'msn.com');
$LinksToCheck = in_array('google.com' , $LinksToRemove);

if (strpos($URLContent, $LinksToCheck) !== 0) {
    $URLContent = preg_replace('#<a.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i', '$1', $URLContent);
}

echo $URLContent;

?>
```

In this example, I want to remove URLs of google.com, yahoo.com and msn.com websites only if any of them found in string $URLContent, but keep any other links.

The result of the previous code is:

```
<p>Google</p><p>AnotherSite</p>
```

but I want it to be:

```
<p>Google</p><p><a href="https://www.anothersite.com/">AnotherSite</a></p>
```

Comment: [in_array](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.in-array.php) can return boolean true or false. [strpos](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php) expects you to give it two strings. So, passing the output of in_array to strpos doesn't really make any sense. I'm not really clear what you were trying to achieve with that.

Comment: What you probably want to do is loop through the items in `$LinksToRemove` deal with each one in turn. You also need to deal with the fact that your regex doesn't distinguish and just removes all links. The regex needs to be dynamically adjusted to take into account the specific URL you're looking for each time, I think.

Answer (score 0):

One solution would be to explode your $URLContent and compare for each value in $LinksToCheck.

It could be like this :

```
<?php
$URLContent = '<p><a href="https://www.google.com/">Google</a></p><p><a href="https://www.anothersite.com/">AnotherSite</a></p>';

$urlList = explode('</p>', $URLContent);

$LinksToRemove = array('google.com', 'yahoo.com', 'msn.com');

$urlFormat = [];
foreach ($urlList as $url) {
    foreach ($LinksToRemove as $link) {
        if (str_contains($url, $link)) {
            $url = '<p>' . ucfirst(str_replace('.com', '', $link)) . '</p>';
            break;
        }
    }
    $urlFormat[] = $url;
}

$result = implode('', $urlFormat);
```

Comment: the </p> isn't constant between links.

Comment: You can explode using anything you want, </a> as well

Comment: it's a random text comes from RSS feed. so, I can't know exactly how the text is formed each time.

Comment: excuse me, what about .net and .co links for example?

Comment: Do you mean for what is shown? Replace using regex, like this 
**$url = '<p>' .preg_replace('#<a.*?>([^>]*)</a>#i', '$1', $link)) . '</p>';**